# Cart page is locking, no xml, no logs, what so ever

Tags: magento, redis, magento-1.9, varnish

We experienced a strange hickup on our magento 1.9 shop.

Our cluster consists of:

1. Load balancer (nginx, with round robin + varnish + NFS)
2. Three PHP nodes to settle front and backend
3. Dedicated CRON server + Redis cache
4. MySQL database

At random times our cart page is locking for no reason.

No entries in the PHP logs with slow/fatal code nor any mySQL locks or hanging processes.

The cart page it self just simply lock. The cart lock may affect multiple storeviews, or only one.

No code have been deployed that can make such an impact on the cart.

The strange thing is that if the cart locks

Our cart page is accessible at https://www.domain.dk/checkout/cart/

If the cart page locks you can access it at https://www.domain.dk/checkout/cart (without trailing slash just fine).

We suspect our redis for creating some funky locks of some sort, that blocks requests/cache writing.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by a locked cart page? Do you mean that the browser just spin and timeout?

Comment: Yeah, the browser just times out. No PHP error logs, ngninx error logs or mysql error logs :)

Comment: Not sure if this works but you can try redirect to `https://www.domain.dk/checkout/cart/index` in nginx.

Comment: That would be an option. The funny thing is its the same code, that is rendered on either of the cart page urls :P

Answer (score 0):

May be different php nodes have different sessions storages and you lost any session data.

Comment: Thats a great thesis. The session and cache stores is shared between the nodes in a individual node.